# Trouble injecting JavaScript into website with cocoa

Tags: javascript, jquery, objective-c, cocoa, code-injection

I am trying to inject some javascript into a site I do not own. The code I am trying to inject is as follows:

```
function submitFormForTime(time){
    $(".t_h").each(function(i, obj){ // find each element with the class t_h
        if ($(this).text() != time) return; // not the right one
        $(this).parent().find("form").each(function(i, obj){
            obj.submit(); // submit that form
        });
    });
}
```

This does not work. It seems that the method I am using, `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`, does not work with nested brackets or whatever. It works fine with simple code.

**The problem is that the code is not being injected at all**

My full code is as follows:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"var script = document.createElement('script');"
                            "script.type = 'text/javascript';"
                            "script.text = \"function submitFormForTime(time){ "
                                "$(\".t_h\").each(function(i, obj){"
                                "if ($(this).text() != time) return;"
                                    "$(this).parent().find(\"form\").each(function(i, obj){"
                                        "obj.submit();"
                                    "});"
                                "});"
                            "}\";"
                            "document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);"]];
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have tried to inspect the webview an check if there is errors in the console ?

Comment: Right click on your webview, then click on inspect element. You will have something similar to a regular browser inspector and you can check if there is something going wrong on the webview side.

Comment: No option for inspect element when I right click. I didn't think that option was available to developers

Comment: You may need to implement the method:
- (NSArray *)webView:(WebView *)sender contextMenuItemsForElement:(NSDictionary *)element defaultMenuItems:(NSArray *)defaultMenuItems
in your webview UI element delegate and return defaultMenuItems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well without alot of trouble i can see a couple a small things. I rewrote it, maybe you can give it a try.

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@
                        "var script = document.createElement('script');"
                        "script.type = 'text/javascript';"
                        "script.text = function submitFormForTime(time) { $('.t_h').each(function(i, obj) { if ($(this).text() == time) $(this).parent().find('form').each(function(i, obj){ obj.submit(); }); }); } document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);"]];
```

I hope it works like that.

Basically i removed some double quotes, and replaced some with single quotes to not have to escape them. And i wrote all the script text on one line.

AND find('form') should be find('.form') if form is a class or find('#form') if form is an id.

Comment: Nope still not working. I am convinced that it is because of the nested brackets as I said. I also didn't think there was any problem with escaping quotes

Comment: Try this : find('form') should be find('.form') if form is a class or find('#form') if form is an id. <form class="form" ... or <form id="form" ...

Comment: The problem is that the code is not being injected AT ALL. At least if it was being injected I could debug my jQuery

Comment: I understand, than i dont know im sorry.